# Schengen visa requirements (company letter and travel insurance)

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork

I would like to apply for a Schengen tourist visa, but I checked out Italy and I wonder about some of its requirements.

**Insurance requirement**

> The insurance must cover medical fees, hospitalization and repatriation costs up to 30,000 euros or SGD 50,000.

Is the sum for all 3 or for each of them?

**Company letter**

Does the letter need to mention all countries in my trip, or Italy only, or Europe?

I hope I can find some enlightenment here.

Comment: Are you sure the company letter is a requirement for tourists? I rather suspect it applies only to business travelers.

Comment: yes it's for tourist @phoog

Comment: Then in that case can you provide a link to the requirement?  As it stands, it makes little sense.  To what "company" does the requirement refer?

Answer (score 1):

The minimum coverage you need is 30,000 Euros and this must include repatriation (return to your home country).

You can easily purchase this online - this is what I do, and my preferred provider is Axa - simply because they have a straight forward website and the entire process takes less than 10 minutes of one's time.

Start here: https://www.axa-schengen.com/en

Your credit card may also provide you insurance. Make sure it meets the guidelines for Schengen (just ask your card issuer for the insurance papers).

The company letter should state (at minimum):

- Your full, legal name
- Your passport number (or other travel document number)
- Your position in the company
- The date you were employed
- Your total salary

In some countries you specifically need permission to leave the job, in that case it should state the start and end of your leave.

If your company is paying part of your expenses (for example, on a business trip), then it should also be mentioned on the letter.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, but I am still not clear whether the 30k euros are for sum of 3 or each of them?

Comment: If you are getting the correct type of insurance, then it will cover all three cases for up to 30,000 EUR. However if you (or your insurance provider) is asking specifics like this, chances are you are not getting the right kind of insurance.

Comment: If you are getting the correct type of insurance, then it will cover all three cases for up to 30,000 EUR. However if you (or your insurance provider) is asking specifics like this, chances are you are not getting the right kind of insurance.